# Convert array of points to line coordinates of SVG as x1, y1, x2, y2

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of points as `[0, 0, 30, 0, 30, 20, 60, 20, 60, 40, 0, 40, 0, 0]`.
I want them to be like `x1, y1, x2, y2` of SVG line coordinates. So that I get 6 lines from them.

It should be like:

1. line1 with x1, y1, x2, y2 coordinates - `0,0,30,0`
2. line2 - `30, 0,30,20`
3. line3 - `30,20,60,20`
4. line4 - `60,20,60,40`
5. line5 - `60,40, 0,40`
6. line6 - `0, 40, 0, 0`

Any sort of looping technique?.

Comment: This not a google. Try it yourself first, before asking here. This is to provide suggestions and help you correct mistakes. Please follow these rules before asking questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a little careful with the indexes you can step through this with a `for` loop. You just need to iterate by steps of two, then in each iteration take four elements. You'll also need to stop the loop 2 elements early because you don't want a group starting with the last two.

I'm not sure the exact format you want the data, but this should be easy to alter to your purpose:

```js
let coords = [0, 0, 30, 0, 30, 20, 60, 20, 60, 40, 0, 40, 0, 0]
let lines = []
for(let i = 0; i < coords.length - 2; i += 2){  // step by 2, stop early
  let [x1, x2, y1, y2] = coords.slice(i, i+4)   // take four elements
  lines.push({x1, x2, y1, y2})
}
console.log(lines)
```